# List of apps written in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

Does anyone know if there exists a gallery of iPhone/iPad apps written in MonoTouch similar to  http://www.phonegap.com/apps/?

Thank you,

Rich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a selection here http://monotouch.info/MonoTouch/Apps

Comment: Never being to that site before. Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The new official URL is: http://xamarin.com/apps

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, the official MonoTouch website now has an App Catalog:
http://monotouch.net/Apps